# boto3 s3 generate_presigned_url ExpiresIn doesn't work as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have tried to generate `pre-signed URL` with 7dsys expiration time.
(It is saying maximum duration is 7days, [AWS S3 pre signed URL without Expiry date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014306/aws-s3-pre-signed-url-without-expiry-date))

```
# It is called and retruned in AWS Lambda
boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_url(
    'get_object',
    Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': object_key},
    ExpiresIn=(60*60*24*7)  # 7days
)
```

However, it seems not to retain the `pre-signed URL` for 7days but just several hours. The `pre-signed URL` just returns the XML format after that.

```
<Error>
  <Code>ExpiredToken</Code>
    <Message>The provided token has expired.</Message>
.
.
.
</Error>
```

It seems even to be different expiration time every time I try, sometimes 5 hours, sometime 12hours.

I don't know why.

Comment: Reading this goes some way to explaining the issue but I think for a 7 day expiry you need to generate the signed URL using IAM user permissions: https://medium.com/@uchimanajet7/point-to-note-when-using-aws-s3-pre-signed-url-aws-s3-6acf4ac1a3ba

Comment: @berimbolo 's reply should be the right answer  `import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

# Get the service client with sigv4 configured
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

# Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
# URL expires in 604800 seconds (seven days)
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'bucket-name',
        'Key': 'key-name'
    },
    ExpiresIn=604800
)

print(url) `

Comment: doesn't works for me

Answer (score 2):

```
import boto3 
from botocore.client 
import Config  
# Get the service client with sigv4 configured 
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))  
# Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name' 
# URL expires in 604800 seconds (seven days) 
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='get_object',Params={
                                                   'Bucket':'bucket-name',
                                                   'Key': 'key-name'
                                                    },ExpiresIn=604800)  
print(url)
```