# boto3 generation url without not expiration

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I need help with the work of the Boto3 library. It has the get_presigned_url method, but for it you need to set the expiration time, my task is to generate a URL that will live forever, for example, use it statically in an application for displaying documents, there is a Django storages library, it does it kind of under the hood

It turns out to generate only a URL with a certain lifetime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 pre signed URL without Expiry date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014306/aws-s3-pre-signed-url-without-expiry-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can't; it’s not possible to create a pre-signed URL that lasts forever.

If you need a URL that allows access to your object with no time limit, [make the S3 object public](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket) & then use the S3 object URL.

i.e.

```py
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

s3_config = Config(
    signature_version = botocore.UNSIGNED,
)

s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=s3_config)

bucket = "{bucket name}"
key = "{object key}"

object_url = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', ExpiresIn=0, Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key})
```